# Randomly replace 10% of the values in two specific column in Dataframe by NA values

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a data set with id, name, maths, science and now I want to replace some values with NA in Maths and Science columns. I tried lot of things but they didn´t worked.

```
    gradebook <- apply (gradebook, 2, function(x) {x[sample( c("Maths","Science"), floor(n/10))] <- NA; x} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `lapply`.  Select the columns of interest, loop over those columns, get a `sample` of 10% of sequence of values and assign them to `NA`, return the column, and assign it to the same columns

```
gradebook[c("Maths", "Science")] <- lapply(gradebook[c("Maths", "Science")], function(x) {
             x[sample(seq_along(x), 0.1 * length(x))] <- NA
             x})
```